# Late Binding, or accessing a page element from its resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, resourcedictionary, late-binding

As a simple example, I have a button in a resource dictionary, which I will store in a ContentControl.  I need a to bind the Button's Visibility property to a checkbox located on the page, but the button is created *before* the checkbox, so my setter won't work.

**Is there a way to make a binding bind after the page is initialized?**  I know I can do it from the code behind, but I'll have a lot of buttons, and it seems rather messy to have parts of the buttons' initialization code in different locations.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
<button  x:Key = "MyButton">Hi There
<button.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="false"/>
        <DataTrigger     // myCheckBox doesn't exist yet...
          Binding="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true"/>
        <DataTrigger/>
    </Style>
</button.Style>
</button>
</ResourceDictionary>

<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CheckBox x:Name = "myCheckBox" Row=1/> //This is made too late to bind my button to

    <ContentControl Content = "{StaticResource MyButton}" Row=2/>

</Grid>
```

I've found things like [lazy loading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avtarsohi/2015/09/14/use-of-deferred-loading-in-xaml/), where you load objects when you need them, and I've explored [making my own binding class](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/wpf-custom-binding-class), but I just don't know where to go with it.

My current favorite idea is something like:

xaml:

```
property="{lateBinding source=whatever path=you.want}"
```

and some generic c# class code:

```
class lateBinding : Binding
{
    OnPageInitialized()
    {
        SetBinding(myObject, myProperty, myBinding);
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine (other than the fact that your code have compile issues that had to be fixed). What happens when you try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works with little changes

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Button  x:Key = "MyButton">Hi There
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox x:Name = "myCheckBox" Grid.Row="1"/> 

        <ContentControl Content = "{StaticResource MyButton}" Grid.Row="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It turns out that I simplified my problem a little to much, so I asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731592/binding-elementname-failing). But this is definitely a great answer to the question I asked. It helped me go in the right direction. Thanks!