# {Binding elementName...} failing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scope

I have created an dummy window with

- a checkbox
- a Button
- a Button inside a custom UserControl

Both Buttons start out Blue, and when the checkbox is checked, they should both turn orange. However, the one inside the user control seems to be ignoring the checkbox. **Why is it failing, and how can I get around this?**

The UserControl I want to insert:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
       DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"


       <Grid>
            <!--MyContent is a dependency property in UserControl1's code behind-->
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyContent}">      
       </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
       <Window.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>

               <Style TargetType="Button">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myCheckbox, Path=isChecked}" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange/>
                       </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>

               <Button x:Key="Button1"  Content="Button1"/>
               <Button x:Key="Button2"  Content="Button2"/>

           </ResourceDictionary>
       </Window.Resources>

       <Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

           <CheckBox x:Name = "myCheckBox" Content="Turn Orange" Grid.Row="0"/>

           <!--This updates when I check myCheckBox-->        
           <ContentControl Content = "{StaticResource Button1}" Grid.Row="2"/>

           <!--This does NOT update when I check myCheckBox-->
           <test:UserControl1 MyContent="{StaticResource Button2}" Grid.Row="2"/>

       </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can't guarantee it; but I have strong feeling `myCheckbox` is out of scope once you are inside of `UserControl1`. I'm guessing you have a System.Data Exception to that effect. Not much you can do about that but not rely on elementName so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it failing

Because there is no CheckBox named "myCheckBox" in the UserControl. The CheckBox in the parent window resides in another naming scope so binding to an ElementName won't work here.

> How can I get around this?

Learn and implement MVVM design pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx. It is *the* recommended design pattern to use when developing XAML based UI applications.

Create view model class that holds the current status of the CheckBox:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And set the DataContext of the window to an instance of this and bind to its IsChecked property instead of binding directly to the CheckBox:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Button x:Key="Button1"  Content="Button1"/>
        <Button x:Key="Button2"  Content="Button2"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <test:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox x:Name ="myCheckBox" Content="Turn Orange" Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>

        <ContentControl Content = "{StaticResource Button1}" Grid.Row="1"/>

        <test:UserControl2 MyContent="{StaticResource Button2}" Grid.Row="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The UserControl should inherit the DataContext of the parent window so don't set the DataContext property explicitly in UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication11.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference myCheckBox from the style, those are two different scopes. Plus the style is targeting a button, but the control is a Window. You'd have to put all the controls within the style in the control template.